# I can't run basic views acivity in android studio by java

Tags: java, android

when I run the app by java languages it appears like that
[enter[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KK2Yr.png) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tE4JQ.png)

I try delete android studio and find many places but it not run. I don't know the way to fix this fault

Comment: dont paste links to images, paste your error log

Comment: Please, [do not upload images of code/data/error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)!

Answer (score 0):

provide your logcat errors. i will edit this answer and try to help you.